# Jquery.load() and script tags inside the file that we want to load

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-loading, script-tag

Well, this is weird, but so simple, when I tried to load before my page changing some content of the main index I noticed that something was going wrong because it showed only the actual year "2017", and now I can confirm it because, creating two files test1.html and test2.html this happened:

Test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test").load("test2.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Test2.html

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa<br>
<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

Result:

[image: result]

So, what can I do to avoid this and show everything without any worries?
Trying to make a separate function doesn't work neither...

**EDIT:**

Now, somebody told me that using document.write is the problem, my problem is that is a simple solution, declaring a html element to write later its content is a little bit less simple and heavier, so, my actual question is know if there is any lightweight replacement for document.write?

Comment: If you don't want everything to be replaced, don't use `document.write`.

Comment: What can do instead if I want to write something without using selectors? @Santi

Comment: I would try `document.body.innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();` and see if that works as you expect, although I'll be honest, I'm not 100% on whether or not that will reproduce the same issue.

Comment: I will try eval() by the moment... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardcoded my own solution to make everything simplier, I create an element with a data attribute called `data-func`, and later I done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     var fncs = $('[data-func]');
     fncs.each(function () {
         $(this).text(window[$(this).data("func")]);
     });
});
```

The function:

```
function getYear() {
    return new Date().getFullYear();
}
```

And the element:

```
<span data-func="getYear"></span>
```

And thats all!